# Python infinite while loop inside a function

Tags: python, function, while-loop

No matter what I try I keep getting an infinite loop with this function:

```
  # Excercise 33 - LPTHW

i = 0 
numbers = []

#Ec 1
#numb = 6
#iplus = 10

def theloop(numb):
        global i
        #i = 0
        #number = []
        while i < numb:
            print "At the top of i is %d" % i
            numbers.append(i)

            i = i + 1
            print "Numbers now: ", numbers
            print "At the bottom i is %d" % i

        print "The numbers: "

        for num in numbers:
            print num

theloop(7)
```

When I run the script it just keeps printing:

```
At the top of i is 0
At the top of i is 0
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this *exactly* the script you're running? Because it works fine for me here.

Comment: Ran the script in Python 3 (correcting the print syntax). Works fine here. Unless numbers.Append() is doing something strange, what you describe cannot happen. Check your indentation.

Comment: LPTHW is a crazy way to learn Python. Look at "Dive into Python 3" or one of the decent tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me as written, but looks to have weird indentation due to use of mixed tabs and spaces.  When I read your script using .readlines, you can see this:

```
 '    def theloop(numb):\n',
 '    \t\tglobal i\n',
 '    \t\t#i = 0\n',
 '            #number = []\n',
 '    \t\twhile i < numb:\n',
 '     \t\t\tprint "At the top of i is %d" % i\n',
 '        \t\tnumbers.append(i)\n',
 '    \n',
 '        \t\ti = i + 1\n',
```

So I'd recommend switching to four spaces everywhere and having another go.  Note the difference in the number of tabs between the print statement and the append/increment statements.

Comment: Thanks @DSM that was the issue. Also thanks James, Satoru & Thomas for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

if you've mixed spaces and tabs then try to run your script like this:

```
python -tt yourscript.py ##this will raise error if you've mixed spaces and tabs
```

this is what I am getting after running your script and it's not infinite.

```
At the top of i is 0
Numbers now:  [0]
At the bottom i is 1
At the top of i is 1
Numbers now:  [0, 1]
At the bottom i is 2
At the top of i is 2
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2]
At the bottom i is 3
At the top of i is 3
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3]
At the bottom i is 4
At the top of i is 4
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
At the bottom i is 5
At the top of i is 5
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
At the bottom i is 6
At the top of i is 6
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
At the bottom i is 7
The numbers: 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: I will start using `-tt` great tip.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like there is an indenting mistake after the following lines:

```
   while i < numb:
        print "At the top of i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)
```

Like James said, it works just fine here as you pasted it, so you might want to check if you have the correct indentation level in your actual code.